# How to compare two case insensitive strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

i have 2 string objects containing same string but case is different,now i wanna compare them ignoring the case sensitivity,how to do that??here is the code...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
void main()  
{  
    NSString *myString1 = @"mphasis";  
    NSString *myString2 = @"MPHASIS";
    if ([myString1 caseInsenstiveCompare:myString2])  
    {  
        NSLog (@"ITS EQUAL");  
    }  
    else  
    {   
        NSLog (@"ITS NOT EQUAL");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: You're almost there. You may want to refer to the docs or even Xcode's autocomplete if you're stuck.

Comment: If you consider an answer to your question to be satisfactory or at least helpful, it's customary to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will increase both your reputation and that of the answerer. It will also make it more likely that someone will bother answering you in the future.

Answer (score 34):

If you look up caseInsensitiveCompare: [in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/caseInsensitiveCompare:) you'll see that it returns an NSComparisonResult rather than a BOOL. Look that up [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult) and you'll see that you probably want it to be NSOrderedSame. So

`if ([myString1 caseInsensitiveCompare:myString2] == NSOrderedSame)`

should do the trick. Or just compare the lowercase strings like Robert suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Just use lowercaseString on both of the strings and then compare them as you would using a normal string equality check. It will still be O(n) so no big deal.

Answer (score 5):

I would rather suggest to add a category on NSString:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualIgnoreCaseToString:(NSString *)iString {
    return ([self caseInsensitiveCompare:iString] == NSOrderedSame);
}
```

With this you can simply call:

```
[myString1 isEqualIgnoreCaseToString:myString2];
```

Answer (score 1):

To save a method call, I used a macro via a `#define`:

```
#define isEqualIgnoreCaseToString(string1, string2) ([string1 caseInsensitiveCompare:string2] == NSOrderedSame)
```

Then call:

```
(BOOL) option = isEqualIgnoreCaseToString(compareString, toString);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one, convert both strings in same case.Here i'm converting it to lower case and then checking it.

```
if ([[myString1 lowercaseString] [myString2 lowercaseString]])
{
 // same
}
```