# How to compare two ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid

I have two Ids

```
85816465-FA7B-48B1-8AD3-7FB0A1B6C011 - 85816465-fa7b-48b1-8ad3-7fb0a1b6c011
```

As you can see, they are almost the same, but there is difference )

85816465-FA7B-48B1-8AD3-7FB0A1B6C011 this code i'm compile by this code

```
   CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
   NSString * uuidString = (__bridge NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
   CFRelease(newUniqueId);
```

after this insert it into database (Postgres) and database converts it onto this

```
85816465-fa7b-48b1-8ad3-7fb0a1b6c011
```

When i'm selecting this inserted Id and trying to compare it with old, Xcode gives me that they are not equal ...
any suggestions?

Comment: please show your Postgres table definition

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089997/how-to-compare-two-case-insensitive-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are comparing the strings convert them to Uppercase if that is the only diffrence using the method

```
uuidString=[uuidString uppercaseString];
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I just chanted case and it works great )

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one ...I hope it may help you

```
NSString *str1 = @"85816465-FA7B-48B1-8AD3-7FB0A1B6C011";
NSString *str2 = @"85816465-fa7b-48b1-8ad3-7fb0a1b6c011";

str1 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
str2 = [str2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

if( [str1 caseInsensitiveCompare:str2] == NSOrderedSame )
    NSLog(@"ITS EQUAL");
else
    NSLog(@"ITS NOT EQUAL");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSRange r = [udidstring1 rangeOfString:udidstring2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if(r.location != NSNotFound)
    {
         NSLog(@"Both UDID are same");
    }
```

or you can try this

```
    if ([udidstring1 caseInsensitiveCompare:udidstring2]==NSOrderedSame) {
            NSLog(@"Both UDID are same");
    }
```